# Prevent a call to a super method from happening multiple times in a proxy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I've written a TypeScript decorator/JavaScript mixin around a React `Component` called `autodispose`.  Suppose that class `A` extends `autodispose(Component)` and class `B` extends `A`.  The mixin ensures that `A.componentWillUnmount()` is called regardless of whether `B.componentWillUnmount()` calls `super.componentWillUnmount()` via a proxy.

(The code is in TypeScript, but the question pertains to JavaScript.)

```ts
export function autodispose<
  T extends Class<React.Component>
>(Target: T) {
  const ObservingComponent = class extends Target {
    constructor(...args: any[]) {
      super(...args);

      // ... mixin setup ...

      this.componentWillUnmount = new Proxy(this.componentWillUnmount, {
        apply: (target, thisArg, fnArgs) => {
          Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, fnArgs);

          if (super.componentWillUnmount) {
            super.componentWillUnmount();
          }

          this.__mixinCleanup();
        },
      });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      if (super.componentWillUnmount) {
        super.componentWillUnmount();
      }

      this.__mixinCleanup();
    }

    private __mixinCleanup() {
      // is a no-op if __mixinCleanup() has already been called
      // ...
    }
  };
}
```

If `B` calls `super.componentWillUnmount()` then the proxy will call `A`'s `componentWillUnmount()` twice--first by `Reflect.apply(target, thisArg, fnArgs)` and then immediately after that.  I need a way to detect if the call to `Reflect.apply()` has already called `super.componentWillUnmount()` and prevent the second call.

I considered temporarily overriding `super.componentWillUnmount` with another Proxy which sets a flag that it's been called, but, unsurprisingly, you can't override `super`'s methods.

If all else fails, I can just make sure that `autodispose` doesn't get called in the prototype chain twice, but this solution would be more ideal.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using a proxy here. Just wrap the function inside a new function.

Comment: You mean you want to detect and handle the case where `B` overrides `componentWillUnmount` but fails to call `super.componentWillUnmount`? I would suggest throwing an error as a developer warning, not trying to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to (temporarily or otherwise) overwrite `B`'s `super.componentWillUnmount` - you did define `A.prototype.componentWillUnmount` yourself! You can just set the flag in there:

```
export function autodispose(Target) {
  return class ObservingComponent extends Target {
    constructor(...args) {
      super(...args);
      // ... mixin setup ...

      this._hasSuperBeenCalled = false;
      let original = this.componentWillUnmount;
      this.componentWillUnmount = function(...args) {
        this._hasSuperBeenCalled = false;
        original.apply(this, args);
        if (!this._hasSuperBeenCalled)
          throw new Error(`Warning: ${this.constructor.name}.componentWillUnmount forgot its super call`);
      };
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
      this._hasSuperBeenCalled = true;
      if (super.componentWillUnmount) {
        super.componentWillUnmount();
      }

      // ...mixin cleanup
    }
  };
}
```